# Does the Linz Ĥ applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩ correctly transition to its final reject state?

Tags: turing-machines, decidability, halting-problem, undecidability, universal-turing-machines

```
// Linz Turing machine H --- H applied to ⟨H⟩ 
H.q0 ⟨H⟩ ⟨H⟩ ⊢* H.qy   // H applied to ⟨H⟩ halts
H.q0 ⟨H⟩ ⟨H⟩ ⊢* H.qn   // H applied to ⟨H⟩ does not halt
Do you halt on your own Turing Machine description ?
```

Of the infinite set of implementations of H every one that transitions to H.qy derives an answer consistent with the behavior of H.

**When we append an infinite loop to the H.qy state we derive Ȟ**

```
Ȟ.q0 ⟨Ȟ⟩ ⟨Ȟ⟩ ⊢* Ȟ.qy ∞ // Ȟ applied to ⟨Ȟ⟩ halts
H.q0 ⟨Ȟ⟩ ⟨Ȟ⟩ ⊢* Ȟ.qn   // Ȟ applied to ⟨Ȟ⟩ does not halt 
Do you halt on your own Turing Machine description ?
```

Of the infinite set of implementations of Ȟ none of them derives an answer consistent with the behavior of Ȟ.

This is because the question:
**Do you halt on your own Turing Machine description ?**
is self-contradictory thus incorrect question for Ȟ.

Yes/no questions intentionally defined to have no correct yes/no answer are incorrect questions. The inability to correctly answer an incorrect question places no actual limit on anyone or anything.

**Two PhD computer science professors agree with this view:**

E C R Hehner. **Objective and Subjective Specifications** WST Workshop on Termination, Oxford. 2018 July 18.
See [https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hehner/OSS.pdf](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ehehner/OSS.pdf)

Bill Stoddart. **The Halting Paradox**
20 December 2017
https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.05340
arXiv:1906.05340 [cs.LO]

## Prior version of Question

By making a slight refinement to the halt status criterion measure that remains consistent with the original a halt decider may be defined that correctly determines the halt status of the conventional halting problem proof counter-examples. This refinement overcomes the pathological self-reference issue that previously prevented halting decidability.

**Does the Linz Ĥ applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩ correctly transition to its final reject state?**

**Simple English version of Olcott's Halt status criterion measure:** Every simulating halt decider that must abort the simulation of its input to prevent its infinite simulation correctly transitions to its reject state.

**Somewhat formalized version of Olcott's Halt status criterion measure:** Let ⟨M⟩ describe a Turing machine M = (Q, Σ, Γ, δ, q₀, □, F), and let w be any element of Σ⁺, A solution of the halting problem is a Turing machine H, which for any ⟨M⟩ and w, performs the computation (Linz 1990:317)

H.q<sub>0</sub>  ⟨M⟩ w ⊢* H.q<sub>y</sub> **----- iff UTM( ⟨M⟩, w ) reaches the final state of M**
H.q<sub>0</sub>  ⟨M⟩ w ⊢* H.q<sub>n</sub> **----- iff UTM( ⟨M⟩, w ) would never reach the final state of M**

Simulating halt decider H performs a pure simulation of its input as if it was a UTM unless and until it detects an infinitely repeating pattern. Then it aborts the simulation of its input and transitions to its final reject state.

The following simplifies the syntax for the definition of the Linz Turing machine Ĥ, it is now a single machine with a single start state. **A copy of Linz H is embedded at Ĥ.qx.**

**Ĥ.q0  ⟨Ĥ⟩  ⊢*  Ĥ.qx  ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩   ⊢*  Ĥ.qy ∞**
**Ĥ.q0  ⟨Ĥ⟩  ⊢*  Ĥ.qx  ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩   ⊢*  Ĥ.qn**

[image]
**Figure 12.3 Turing Machine Ĥ**

**Can the correct simulation of ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ by embedded_H possibly transition to ⟨Ĥ⟩.qn ?**

[image]

**Linz, Peter 1990**. An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata. Lexington/Toronto: D. C. Heath and Company. (318-320)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The center state is called embedded_H because the Linz text explains that that Ĥ is created entirely from prepending and appending states to the original Linz H. The Linz notation has been simplified. The notation refers to the definition of Ĥ near that bottom of the Linz proof shown above.

Ĥ.q0 ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* embedded_H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* Ĥ.qy ∞
Ĥ.q0 ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* embedded_H ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⊢* Ĥ.qn

When Ĥ is applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩ it copies its input and then transitions to the the start state of the original Linz H. Because embedded_H is a simulating halt decider the first thing that it does is simulate ⟨Ĥ⟩ applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩.

We can see that this would repeat in an endless cycle unless embedded_H (shown at qx) sees this repeating pattern and aborts its simulation.

[image]

Because neither Ĥ applied to ⟨Ĥ⟩ nor ⟨Ĥ⟩ ⟨Ĥ⟩ correctly simulated by embedded_H would ever stop running unless embedded_H aborts its simulation embedded_H is necessarily correct to transition to its final reject state of Ĥ.qn.

Linz, Peter 1990. An Introduction to Formal Languages and Automata. Lexington/Toronto: D. C. Heath and Company. (317-320)